# Higher Order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I'm given an ODE with powers greater than 2

$\frac{d^5y}{dx^5} - 4\frac{d^3y}{dx^3} = 0$

and am asked to find the general solution. How do I go about doing it?

If someone could go possibly explain through for me, that would be good :)

Comment: Do you know about the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: yes so the ODE would become $λ^5 - 4λ^3 = 0$ then taking out a factor of $λ^3$ becomes $λ^3(λ^2 - 4) = 0$ so $λ^3 = 0$ and $λ^2= 4$?

Answer (score 3):

Try $y'''=t$ The equation reduces to $t''=4t$. The general solution of this is : hover to see

> $C_1e^{2x}+C_2e^{-2x}=t$

Can you carry on from here?

One solution is obviously $y=0$

Answer (score 0):

If you start from what Awesome suggested, you should notice that every time you will move from $y'''$ to $y''$ to $y'$ and finally to $y$ the only thing you will be doing is to integrate the integration constant since $t=C_1e^{2x}+C_2e^{-2x}$. So, basically, to this solution, you will add a quadratic polynomial in $x$.

Comment: okay so the final answer would be $y = C_1e^{2x} + C_2xe^{-2x}$? but the thing is if I work by using the characteristic polynomial, what would be different?

Comment: No. It will be $C_1 e^{2x}+C_2 e^{-2x}++_3+C_4x+C_5 x^2$. You seem to forget the integration constant at each step after having obtained $y'''$